# Close event not working when opening and closing multiple Task-items

Tags: vba, outlook

I got the following situation.

- Open an outlook task
- The open event is executed
- Open a second outlook task
- The open event is executed
- Close the first task
- No close event is executed !!!
- Close the second task
- The close event is executed

Does anybody have a clue what is happening here ?
Did I do some bad programming ? I have placed my code below.

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards,

Wamor

```
Public WithEvents objInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors
Public WithEvents objJournal As Outlook.JournalItem
Public WithEvents objTask As Outlook.TaskItem

Dim objOldTask As Outlook.TaskItem

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objInspectors = Outlook.Inspectors
    Set objTask = Nothing
    Set objJournal = Nothing
    Set objOldTask = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub objInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    If TypeOf Inspector.CurrentItem Is TaskItem Then
       Set objTask = Inspector.CurrentItem
    End If
    If TypeOf Inspector.CurrentItem Is JournalItem Then
        Set objJournal = Inspector.CurrentItem
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub objTask_Open(Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "TaskItem open event"
End Sub

Private Sub objTask_close(Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "TaskItem close event"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course - you have multiple open objects but only a single variable to store a reference to them.

The standard way of dealing with problems like this is to have a wrapper class that has Inspector and the Item (two items - TaskItem and JournalItem in your case) as variables. TaskOpen and TaskClose event handlers will be methods on that wrapper class.
When NewInspector event fires, create an instance of your wrapper class and populate its properties. Add the wrapper class to a global list. 
When close event fires, remove the wrapper class from the list.